# Best approach for RESTful Web Api with multiple Update/Put actions?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

When making RESTful services, I find myself confused on how to handle different types of updates in a resource. With MVC we could have different actions with different models working smoothly, but as we move to Web API and try to implement a REST approach I get myself tied to two options: PUT and POST.

And that's not enough.

If I have a very big and complex resource, like a User's profile in a social website with lots of properties and possible bounds with other resources, just trying to make any possible change go through the same "PUT" isn't going to work, it would create a massive Spaghetti Updater Monster.

I've found different solutions to this problem though:

1. Use overloads (with different models as param). Still not good as this type of bifurcation can make it hard to maintain and/or troubleshooting.
2. Use PATCH verb. Though this would still require me to overload it many times for each update possibility and WEB API doesn't have native support for it.
3. Create more Controllers: Personally I've used this approach in an MVC/Command way: I can consider the "bound" a resource and make a Controller like: FriendsController, FavouritesController, LikesController, MainPhotoController, ans so... which are "user features/properties/possible bounds with other resources". It works for me and makes things simpler and smoother.
4. Looks like there's another similar way but instead of creating Controllers for everything, creating "paths", so I could have "UserController/favourites/", "UserController/Likes", etc.

I know that in SW architecture there's never an absolute right way and it all depends on your requirements, but even so there are patterns and best practices so, which one of those looks like a best practice to you? Or does none of those look like a good approach?

Many Thanks.

Comment: If you're writing an RPC API, don't try to cram it into REST. It won't fit. A `/user/LikePost/$postId` is RPC, whichever way you look at it (a "Like" is not a resource). So, option 3. You also don't _have_ to go REST when using WebAPI.

Comment: Option 3 is the strategy I go with.

Comment: @Matthew You can't just say that without giving a reason.

Comment: Well, I suppose I will stick to my Option 3 approach, good to know that I can just make some REST/RPC hybrid using HTTP verbs when useful but also having Action names. I'm going to stick to HTTP verbs to name Actions though, but will have different Controllers to divide the big problem into smaller ones.